# use the functions without its parameters

Tags: php, function, parameters, global

I am using 2 regex functions here and I wanna make another function which returns false when the 2 regex are both `false` and if not, then `true`.

The problem here is when I wanna use the 2 regex functions in the third one, I have to give them parameters, which is not necessary I think, because the third function will only return a simple true or false. I get an `undefined variable` whenever I give parameters to the 2 regex functions in the 3rd one.

I tried using `global` variables which works but since its a bad practice I am looking for a better solution.

Code:

```
function regex1($input)
{
    $regex= "/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/";
    if (!preg_match($regex, $input))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function regex2($input)
{
    $regex= "/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/";
    if (!preg_match($regex, $input)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkBoth()
{
    if (regex1($input) === false || regex2($input) === false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The checkBoth function I am using in my other file like this together with the other 2 regex functions:

```
 if (!regex1($input))
 {
      // show error at the same time
 }
 if (!regex2($input))
 {
      // show error at the same time
 }

if(checkBoth())
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: you have a typo both the function are named  regex1 ..

Comment: variable scope issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry, that was a typo when I edited this in here

Comment: @SC92  ok .. typo  corrected ..

Answer (score 0):

```
function regex2($input,$secondVar=false)
{....
```

Later in code in place where you need just add:

```
if($secondVar !== false){
// do whatever...
}
```

If you can't user "false" you can just empty string '' or any other value that will not appear there.